# Run thread after app closes with Timer

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, gps

I am making a test app which starts a Thread on a button click. 
I am finding location through GPS within the thread.
But when I close the app, the thread gets destroyed.
I want to start a thread that would start on button click and run for 10 minutes finding location via GPS.
Even if the user closes the app, the thread currently running should run for 10 minutes and find location.
I am unable to do the timer part and keeping the thread running when I close the app.
Here is my code.
[My Code on Pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/s5mZR23u)

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing is the normal Android application lifecycle.
When an application gets put in the background (the user never actually 'closes' an app, they just activate another app, or the home screen), the OS is free to destroy the application.

To keep something running in the background as you describe, you'll need to implement an [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).